# Alpha Blend two ARGB colors in 32bit form

Tags: c#, colors

i am writing some C# code to alpha blend two 32bit pixels in `ARGB` form like this:

```
Red = 0xFFFF0000 with an Alpha of 255 "FF"
```

Anyways, I am trying to avoid byte per byte blending like this:

```
public static Color Blend(this Color color, Color backColor, double amount)
    {
        amount = (255 - amount);
        byte r = (byte)((color.R * amount / 255) + backColor.R * (255 - amount) / 255);
        byte g = (byte)((color.G * amount / 255) + backColor.G * (255 - amount) / 255);
        byte b = (byte)((color.B * amount / 255) + backColor.B * (255 - amount) / 255);
        return Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
    }
```

I'm trying to make this as fast as possible without using double. Is there an equation that can alpha blend two pixels in integer form without breaking it into bytes?

P.S. I cannot use any .Net framework calls like Color.FromARGB and stuff.

Thank's

Comment: You literally use Colors.FromArgb in your example code block.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [the other .FromArgb method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hstcth9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that accepts an integer alpha parameter.

Comment: I cant use that with what I am doing sadly. I plan on writing the equation that does what I want to Assembly.

Comment: Then read [this SO answer about ARGB blending](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944095/how-to-mix-two-argb-pixels)

Comment: Already read it before asking my question. I need an equation that does not do "byte per byte" blending rather blending of the whole ARGB value so that I can save CPU calculations and time.