# Blue to Gray CSS color calculate in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, colors, graph-algorithm

How do you calculate the div bg color from blue to lightblue to gray based on a percentage value? ex. if the value equals 100%, the div's bg color is `#0000FF`; if the value equals 50%, it's light blue; if the value equals 0, the bg color is gray.

Does there have a algorithm work on this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can check out this question, it uses math to determine the proper color of two RGB colors mixed together with a weighting factor: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1892036/420001

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you'll want the hexadecimal value in RGB. For that, you can use this function:

```
function hexToRgb(hex) {
    return {
        r: parseInt(hex.substring(1, 3), 16),
        g: parseInt(hex.substring(3, 5), 16),
        b: parseInt(hex.substring(5, 7), 16)
    };
}
```

Then, just apply the weights to each component:

```
function blendColors(colorA, colorB, weight) {
    return {
        r: Math.floor(colorA.r * (1 - weight) + colorB.r * weight),
        g: Math.floor(colorA.g * (1 - weight) + colorB.g * weight),
        b: Math.floor(colorA.b * (1 - weight) + colorB.b * weight)
    };
}
```

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/8Qh7Y/)

Answer (score -2):

You can make a json object and directly refer to it while changing the color

```
var colorMap = new Object();
colorMap["100%"] = "#0000FF";
colorMap["50%"] = "lightBlue";
colorMap["0%"] = "gray";
```

and then use this map whenevr you change the background color

```
var percentageValue = '100%'; //you can pass this value inside a function also
document.getElementById("obj").style.background-color=colorMap[percentageValue];
```