# Child and parent element, both with RGBA backgrounds. How do I determine the "equivalent" rgba?

Tags: css, background, background-color, rgba

Say I have:

```
<div class="dark">
    <div class="lite"></div>
</div>

<div class="medium"></div>
```

and some css:

```
.dark {background:rgba(10,10,10,0.8);}
.lite {background:rgba(200,200,200,0.5);}
```

What calculation is needed if I want `medium` to have the same rgba value as the combined `dark > lite`? I thought a simple normalized calculation (normalize each color component and multiply) would work but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 0):

Such calculation cannot be done using CSS, but your goal can be achieved using `background-blend-mode: multiply`. However, this is not widely supported yet: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-backgroundblendmode .

You probably need a JavaScript solution for that, check out those plugins for jQuery:
https://github.com/farski/jquery-blend/
https://github.com/jquery/jquery-color/

Also, depending on the nature of your problem it may be possible to solve it using CSS precompilers but that will work only if you need to get this color once, and not dynamically.

In LESS this would be as simple as this:

```
@dark: rgba(10,10,10,0.8);
@lite: rgba(200,200,200,0.5);

.dark {background: @dark;}
.lite {background: @lite;}
.medium {  
    background-color: mix(@dark, @lite, 50%);  
}
```

Comment: I think he just wants to know how to calculate it so he can assign the appropriate value to `.medium`, without necessarily performing the calculation *in* CSS.

Comment: Yes, just the math formula is what I'm after.

Comment: Than this may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892020/mixing-two-rgb-color-vectors-to-get-resultant