# Change the nearby pixels of a given color in transparent

Tags: c#, windows

Given an image, I want to convert its pixels nearby a specified color, like `Color.FromArgb(210, 189, 51)`, to transparent area.

I tried this:

```
public Bitmap MakeTransparent(Image image,Color clr)
{
    Bitmap b = new Bitmap(image);

    var replacementColour = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255);
    var tolerance = 1;

    for (int i = b.Size.Width - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        for (int j = b.Size.Height - 1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            var col = b.GetPixel(i, j);

            if (clr.R - col.R < tolerance &&
                clr.G - col.G < tolerance &&
                clr.B - col.B < tolerance)
            {
                b.SetPixel(i, j, replacementColour);
            }
        }
    }

    b.MakeTransparent(replacementColour);

    return b;
}
```

But the result is wrong.

Comment: You have specified what you have tried, but forget to specify what problem did you faced. So what's the problem?

Comment: The code doesn't work properly, it will convert to transparent area unspecified colors also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should learn about [metrics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_%28mathematics%29).

Anyway, if bad colors are converted it's **obviously** due to your test:

```
if (clr.R - col.R < tolerance && clr.G - col.G < tolerance && clr.B - col.B < tolerance)
```

If `clr` is say `(100,100,100)` ([light gray](http://www.colorhexa.com/646464)) any color with RGB less than 99 will pass the test. Like `(75,57,37)` ([dark shitty brown](http://www.colorhexa.com/4b3925))...

You may use [Math.Abs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.math.abs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
if (Math.Abs(clr.R - col.R) < tolerance &&
    Math.Abs(clr.G - col.G) < tolerance &&
    Math.Abs(clr.B - col.B) < tolerance)
```

As a remark, if `tolerance` is `1` you check for `Math.Abs(d) < 1` which is equivalent to `d == 0`. So if tolerance is `1`, you actually check for color equality.

You may use:

```
if (Math.Abs(clr.R - col.R) <= tolerance &&
    Math.Abs(clr.G - col.G) <= tolerance &&
    Math.Abs(clr.B - col.B) <= tolerance)
```

In this case, you check for color equality when `tolerance` is equal to `0`.

Also, you should directly set the matching pixels to transparent instead of set it to white and use your previous function:

```
var replacementColour = Color.Transparent;

...  // for loops

if (Math.Abs(clr.R - col.R) < tolerance &&
    Math.Abs(clr.G - col.G) < tolerance &&
    Math.Abs(clr.B - col.B) < tolerance)
{
    b.SetPixel(i, j, replacementColour);
}
```

Doing this may not be **the** good way, as *color distances* is a big subject. You should learn about that:

- [How to compare RGB colors in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3968179/compare-rgb-colors-in-c-sharp)
- [Definition of color difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference)
- …

Comment: This is just work like  if(clr==col), it is only convert the exact color only not near all colors.

Comment: It tolerance is `1` indeed you check for equality. You may use `<=` instead of `<` or use a bigger tolerance to capture more colors.

Comment: great it works. Can you suggest what is the min and max limit for tolerance?

Comment: `Math.Abs(clr.X - col.X)` is in `[0, 255]`. If you use `<`, `tolerance` make sense in [0, 256] (0 for never convert, 256 for always convert). If you use `<=` it will be [-1, 255] (-1 for never, 255 for always). But this is a scholar question and ask for a response on SO doesn't help you.

Comment: If I use use upto 255 it is not recommended right, because all colors will convert to transparent so only I asked this.