# Java to C# Bitmap.createBitmap

Tags: java, c#

Trying to convert this OpenCV java code over to C#.
[OpenCV Android Background Subtraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9246528/opencv-android-background-subtraction)

Mostly working but am stumbling on this line

```
bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mFGMask.cols(), mFGMask.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Utils.matToBitmap(mFGMask, bmp);
```

So there apparently is no createBitmap method. Can any C# experts suggest how I might properly convert the above?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6782489/create-bitmap-from-a-byte-array-of-pixel-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  [System.Drawing.Bitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap(v=vs.110).aspx) class for creating bitmaps.

If you want to remove background (if I understood correctly), consider these useful links:

- [Change the nearby pixels of a given color in transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29511077/3110834)
- [Color Replacer](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42869/Color-Replacer)
- [Bitmap.MakeTransparent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.bitmap.maketransparent(v=vs.110).aspx)