# How to add 2 System.Drawing.Color?

Tags: c#, colors, c#-2.0

How to add 2 System.Drawing.Color, which is equivalent to System.Windows.Media.Color.Add(). I need this because, I am working on 2.0 framework where System.Windows.Media is unsupported. Please help me on this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to mix colors "naturally" with C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398224/how-to-mix-colors-naturally-with-c)

Comment: I tried that, it wasn't useful.

Comment: **it wasn't useful** is quite disheartening to hear, maybe you could quote any specific issue or problem with the outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to consider *color context* too it's a little bit long to write in an answer. You  may use Reflector (for example) to disassemble `System.Windows.Media.Color.op_Addition` method (stripping what you do not need in your implementation).