# What color format allows for correct "adding" or "mixing" of the color value?

Tags: javascript, c#, css, cryptography, user-experience

I need to represent the addition of numbers (scientific data) into the corresponding "real" color.  (additive mixing)

e.g.  Red + Blue = magenta

However, there could be a small percent of red, and a large percent of blue, that would change the shade of green.

**Question**

Is there a color format (RGB, HEX, etc) or some method I can use to easily calculate the corresponding color?

**Background**

I need to [animate cryptography](https://youtu.be/wXB-V_Keiu8?t=2m43s) using the "color mixing" analogy. A B and C represent a color each.  The color combinations I need to demonstrate are:

- A
- B
- C
- A + B
- C + B
- A + B + C

My goal is to take a large number (private key) and make that represent a color... diluting 96 bits of entropy into a RGB, HSV or some other value that can be "added".

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. What are example inputs and outputs? If you're trying to *average* colors, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/398268/781792) which recommends averaging the Lab space numbers (instead of RGB numbers).

Comment: additive: red + blue = magenta, subtractive: red + blue = purple. which of those do you actually mean?

Comment: @grexter89 yes that I what I mean, I need to programmatically reflect what happens with combining paint colors

Comment: What formats will the input colors have? And what do you want for output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The example video you linked is uses color addition (and is really cool, so +1). The tipoff is the actual lamps they use before the animation: [Light (electromagnetic radiation) is additive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_color). Wikipedia's example image matches your example, Red + Blue = Magenta.

[image]

The other key concept of the video is the inverse color, which the video describes as "the complimentary color, which when added to it [the original color] produces white"

Mathematically, you can apply this to any color operation and representation to get the visual effect you want, *as long as* the operation you choose has an exact mathematic inverse. To demonstrate, let's look at the example they give referring to the [list of web colors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors#HTML_color_names) and the above image.

Alice secret color: Red. `#FF0000`
Alice's public color: Cyan. `#00FFFF`
Technically, the web name for this is Aqua, but it's easy to verify that `#FF0000` + `#00FFFF` = `#FFFFFF` White, so it's the same thing.
(They state the assumption that it's hard to figure out that Red + Cyan = White; this is clearly false, but it's the necessary conceit for the visual color representation).
Color Bob wants to share with Alice: Yellow `#FFFF00`
Color Bob actually transmits: Green (= Yellow + Cyan) `#008000`
Color Alice decodes from Green: Yellow (= Red + Green)

But wait! The last two steps don't make sense.

```
Green   = Yellow  + Cyan
#008000 = #FFFF00 ? #00FFFF

Yellow  = Red     + Green
#FFFF00 = #FF0000 ? #008000
```

And yet every step of this matches the additive color wheel from Wikipedia. You've probably figured that much out for yourself already. The reason color addition works so well for physical light is that real intensity is unbounded. Our eyes are analog and our pupils will dilate and constrict for dimmer or brighter colors automatically. (And we involuntarily close our eyes against super-intense light).

The trouble with digital representations of color is that they are bounded, meaning they can experience overflow. You've tagged the question with [css](/questions/tagged/css), which is no exception. There are several color representations [available in CSS](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#colorunits), including name, RGB Hexadecimal triplet or sextuplet, RGB on a 100% scale, and Hue-Saturation-Lightness (HSL) as @JBzd points out. All of these are bounded, and the W3C specification describes the intended behavior of values that are out-of-bound: values are variously clipped or constrained to the gamut of allowed values. Picking one schema isn't going to save you from the inherit bounds.

What this means for your animation is that if you blindly add the color values together, then you will end up with white, `#FFFFFF`, `rgb(100%, 100%, 100%)`, or `hsl(0, 100%, 100%)` for a large number of combinations. (In fact, this would happen for exactly half of every possible combination of two colors. That's not very visually interesting if you're allowing the full range of input colors.) Indeed, with simple overflow capping our final two examples from the video would produce:

```
Yellow  + Cyan    = ? 
#FFFF00 + #00FFFF = #FFFFFF : white!

Red     + Green   = ?
#FF0000 + #008000 = #FF8000 : kind of orange, actually.
```

The only conclusion is that digital addition is not equivalent to physical addition. This goes back to the fundamental difference between physical and digital representations I described above. The distinction is not lost on photographers, programmers, et al. and so there exist a large variety of color manipulation and combination operations, referred to 'in the trade' as [blend modes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes). As it turns out, the blend mode that most closely matches visual color addition is called [Screen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes#Screen). Adapting wikipedia's language to our cryptographic example:

> With Screen blend mode the values of the two colors are inverted, multiplied, and then inverted again. The result is a brighter picture.
>
> *screen(a,b) = 1 - (1 - a)x(1 - b)*, where A is Alice's secret color and B is the color Bob sent to Alice.

But does it work? The CSS3 standard includes screen as one of its blend modes, and it should work fairly nicely for whatever animation effect you want to define. Check it out:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

canvas.width = 300;
canvas.height = 300;

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

/* globalCompositeOperation :
  normal | multiply | screen | overlay | 
  darken | lighten | color-dodge | color-burn | hard-light | 
  soft-light | difference | exclusion | hue | saturation | 
  color | luminosity
*/
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'screen';

//red
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(255,0,0)';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(150, 100, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();

//green
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,255,0)';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(100, 200, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();

//blue
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(0,0,255)';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(200, 200, 100, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

This is a simple snippet adapted from [this excellent CSS Tricks article on blend modes](https://css-tricks.com/basics-css-blend-modes/). All it does is create a canvas with 3 overlapping circles of our familar RGB primary colors and sets the canvas composite operation to 'screen', and just like that, CSS does the hard work of replicating the color addition example.

Answer (score 2):

Look at HSL (hue-saturation-lightness), you could define ranges of hue that you determine to be certain colors and may have to convert between RGB in order to add/subtract colors and convert to HSL to determine what color you consider it. See this post for conversion algorithms: [HSL to RGB color conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353211/hsl-to-rgb-color-conversion).

Comment: I didn't think of this when I was making my own answer, but the benefit of HSL is that the hue part handles overflows automatically. The Hue is measured on a scale of 0 to 360 in degrees, which is why the HSL color selectors make use of a circle. If you add two hue numbers, you'll wrap around to a new hue automatically and can easily undo the operation with subtraction. +1